# HTML Centering a table row with a width of 110%

Tags: php, html

I have a table row within an HTML email that won't fit everything in unless I make the width 110%.

The only problem is now the table extends to the right. The whole table is set to a width of 600px.

I have found that increasing the width to 110% is the only way I can make the text not wrap on a phone.

Can someone please tell me how to center this row even though the width is extended?

The code is -

```
<div style="margin-bottom: 30px; margin-top: 30px;">

<table class="td" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="6" style="width: 110%; font-family: 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Roboto, Arial, sans-serif; border-left: none; border-right: none; border-top: 1px solid #000; border-bottom: 1px solid #000;" border="0"; align="center">
<tbody>                                         
<?php $items = $order->get_items();
foreach ($items as $item) {
$product = new WC_Product($item['product_id']);?>                                           <tr>   
<td><?php echo $product->get_image($size = 'shop_thumbnail'); ?></td>
<td><?php echo $product->get_title(); ?> </td>
<td><a href="<?php echo $url = get_permalink($product->id).'#reviews'; ?>" style="background-color: #000; color: #fff; text-decoration: none; padding: 10px;">REVIEW NOW</a></td>
</tr>
<?php                                           
}                                           
?>                                          
</tbody>                                        
</table>                                        
</div>
```

Thanks!!

A pic is attached where you can see 'review now' section extending past the sections above. I just want to center this.

[image]

Comment: Add this on the tables parent `margin-left: -5%; margin-right: -5%;`

Comment: Make the font size smaller

Comment: it seems you forgot to add opening **<tr>** tag and please provide output with desire output so that all can understand better.

Comment: Sorry I've added a pic so you can see what the output looks like. The <tr> tag is there.. it's just scrolled all the way right for some reason.    Jeremiah where do I put that code exactly? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use the "nowrap" keyword

```
<td nowrap><?php echo $product->get_image($size = 'shop_thumbnail'); ?></td>
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to check the table-properties:
[Tablepropertie](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_table.asp)